# Spring Boot DTO/Payload validation with extra not required fields

Tags: spring, rest, bean-validation, spring-restcontroller, spring-validator

In Spring Boot applications, while implementing REST APIs, validation is done of the DTO object received by the server.

We can easily validate **the required fields** of DTO objects by validation annotations.

But I want to send error response for the payload **where extra not required fields exist.**

So validation should fail for the payloads like below:

```
{
    "data": {
        "type": "user",
        "attributes": {
            "firstName": "Kazi Mahbubur",
            "lastName": "Rahman",
            "age": 30,
            "x": "x",
            "y": "y",
            "z": "z",
        }
    }
}
```

In the above request body (JSON type), the `x, y, z` attributes are not required according to REST API spec. Attributes `x, y, z` are unexpected and not required fields.

How to achieve this validation fail using Spring Bean Validation?

Or, the best way to handle this scenario as a DTO/payload validation fail?

Comment: Why don't you ignore unknown fields? That's the standard way of handling unknown fields. If still if you want to handle then this can be directly handled using `@Valid` annotation. You need to either add custom  validator or add code in the service layer to validate such errors.

Comment: @sonus21, Although I said DTO validation, it's actually payload validation, because when DTO is made extra fields are discarded automatically. Anyway, as you told, `@Valid` annotation only validate required fields in the DTO object. It can't detect that there are extra fields while converting into DTO and validate afterwards.

Comment: is `attributes` a map? If the attribute is not a map then you can use the approach of `JsonAnySetter` and `JsonAnyGetter`.

Comment: @sonus21, I didn’t get your ideas. Would you please elaborate by posting an answer.

Comment: Can you provide the POJO/DTO that maps this JSON to java object?

Comment: @sonus21 you can consider the DTO has only required fields.

Comment: See it's not clear what's your POJO, without knowing that I can't say anything.